# how to make my html element not participate in elementFromPoint

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a testing project. I am trying to use the document.elementFromPoint(x, y) to get elements for testing. However, I have a use-case where I dont want certain elements to be findable using the elementFromPoint. Is there any attribute that I can change to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) you can use the CSS rule `pointer-events: none` to achieve this.